# Android searching database before adding new value

Tags: android

I have a QR List Adapter where I add values (qr code and youtube id):

```
public void add(String qrcode, String ytid){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.QRCODE, qrcode);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.YT_ID, ytid);
    context.getContentResolver().insert(YouListContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    QRItem item = new QRItem(YouListContentProvider.lastId, qrcode, ytid);
    list.getQRItems().add(item);

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I want to be able to search the database beforehand and if the values (QRCODE and youtube ID) already exists (the video is already in the database) then not to add them to the list. My database helper looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            +ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            +QRCODE+" TEXT, "
            +YT_ID+" TEXT )");
    PutValues(db);

}
```

Comment: Create an index for the QRCODE and YT_ID columns.

Comment: I have a question unrelated to your question here: what is `list`? Is it an `ArrayList` (or just a `List`) or a `ListView`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the `onCreate()` method. I suggest that you create an index for the `QRCODE` and `YT_ID` columns:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + ID  +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + QRCODE + " TEXT, "
            + YT_ID  +" TEXT,
            + UNIQUE (QRCODE, YT_ID) )");
    PutValues(db);

}
```

Now SQLite will not allow you to insert a row where both the `QRCODE` and `YT_ID` are the same as an existing row.

Comment: But should I make some sort of if-statement inside the public void Add with the UNIQUE variable so that if it already exists it shouldn't be added? Or where should I make the query?

Comment: @user2107043 With the `UNIQUE` constraint on your table, you no longer need an `if` statement to check if the row already exists in your table before adding it. I believe `ContentResolver.insert()` will throw an exception if you attempt to add a duplicate, but I'm not entirely certain. I suggest that you test it further to find out for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
   UNIQUE (QRCODE, YT_ID) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
```

Comment: What if you want to provide an error dialog when attempting to add a duplicate? `ON CONFLICT IGNORE` won't allow you to do this will it? (p.s. Perhaps the OP doesn't care, but I have a similar situation where I'd be interested in knowing in more detail how this solution works.)

Comment: there are several options that make SQlite report failure in case of conflict, depending on what you want to do with the transaction - you may want to check http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html